# redirection of ip

Tags: redirect

i want when users will type http://x.x.x.x they will see the content of http://x.x.x.y/feeders/den but url will be http://x.x.x.x

can you please help

Answer (score 0):

In apache you can do that by changing the DocumentRoot in your virtual host: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: thanks but i dun have www .i have it but it is empty.can i point to /home/abc/public_html/